# Alert or Confirm before href

Tags: php

How to make confirm tab before page redirects to calculation php?

```
echo '<form action="include/reserve.php?Nr='.$row['Nr'].'" method="post">
     <input class="button1" type="submit" name="reserve" value="Reserve" />
     </form>';
```

Comment: You need to ask in detaill. Do specify the context also.

Comment: You ask about `href` but the posted code doesn't include any link? And what do you mean by "confirm tab"? Clarity is important.

Answer (score 1):

With some javascript

```
document.querySelector('.button1').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do whatever you want

    //Then get your form element with js and call .submit();
});
```